# high side vs low side load control

Tags: theory

*Background*

Fairly standard scenario - I have an inductive load (servo or something similar) that I turn on and off as needed (several times per hour, nothing high frequency). In a scenario where the voltage of the driving circuit is different from the voltage of the load (3.3V micro controlling a 6V servo), an N-channel MOSFET is easier to use as a switch because fewer components are required.

*Question*

In this scenario, I've often heard an analogy used to advocate for a P-channel MOSFET on the high side rather than the N-channel - that "it's better to turn off the faucet than to plug the sink." What's the actual driver for this? I feel that the water analogy becomes a little stretched here - the risk with plugging a sink is that it overflows. The same thing won't happen in a circuit. What's the detriment to low side control?

Comment: Here is a nice pdf from ON discussing high side vs low in automotive applications: http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/TND384-D.PDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no detriment to low side control if you're using an N channel MOSFET as a low side switch and you've got 3.3 volts for gate drive and that 3.3 volts will fully enhance the switch.

There's a small penalty to pay for using a P channel MOSFET as a high side switch with 3.3 volt gate drive and a more positive source supply, and that's that since in order to fully turn off the MOSFET, its gate must get close to  the source voltage.  That isn't possible with 3.3 volt drive since it can only rise to 3.3 volts, so another transistor must be used - N type with a pullup to V+ - so that when the 3.3 volt drive goes low the transistor cuts off, which will force the PMOSFET gate to V+ through the pullup, turning it off as well.

There are substantial penalties to pay for using N channel MOSFETS as high side switches, since to fully enhance them requires that the gate voltage be higher than the source voltage.

With the load connected to the source, in order to fully enhance the MOSFET, the gate voltage must rise to a voltage higher than the drain voltage in order for the supply voltage to appear across the load. Here are the circuits, and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tipfngr7cqngafb/MOSFET%20switches.asc?dl=0) is the LTspice circuit list for anyone who's interested in running a simulation:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that a preference for high side switching comes from the high voltage area.

If you work with high voltages there is a good reason not to switch on the low side because this leaves your load completely on a high voltage. Bad things will happen if you touch it accidentally.

In cars the low side is normally connected to the car body. In this case high side switching is easier. And it is safer since a short cut will not harm you as long as the load is switched off.